# How can I split test methods for reuse in multiple case with Minitest?

Tags: ruby, refactoring, minitest, reusability, code-reuse

I blocked for refactor my code in my **Minitest** files.

I have this example:

**test_calls.rb**

```
describe Aircall::Calls do
 before do
  @call_by_id = DefaultAircall::AIRCALL.calls.get_by_id(34043501)
  @call_by_user_id = DefaultAircall::AIRCALL.calls.get_by_user_id(80603)
 end

 describe "By id" do
  it "is Hash" do
    @call_by_id.must_be_instance_of Hash
  end

  it "no error return" do
    @call_by_id['error'].must_be_nil
  end
 end

 describe "by user id" do
  it "is Hash" do
    @call_by_user_id.must_be_instance_of Hash
  end

  it "no error return" do
    @call_by_user_id['error'].must_be_nil
  end
 end
end
```

**test_users.rb**

```
describe Aircall::Users do
describe "By id" do

  before do
    @user_by_id = DefaultAircall::AIRCALL.users.get_by_id(80603)
  end

  it "is Hash" do
    @user_by_id.must_be_instance_of Hash
  end

  it "no error return" do
    @user_by_id['error'].must_be_nil
  end

 end
end
```

Ideally, I want split my code in another file, like this:

```
class DefaultTest
 def initialize(element_to_test)
  @element_to_test = element_to_test
 end

 def defaults_tests
  describe "default" do
   it "is Hash" do
    @element_to_test.must_be_instance_of Hash
   end

   it "no error return" do
    @element_to_test['error'].must_be_nil
   end
  end
 end
end
```

So, I could be import my **default tests** in my different tests files.

I don't know if it's possible and how. I have succeeded one time I think, but the test don't appear in console. If I call a class method who run some Minitest tests, my task (who run the test) not accounting my default tests.

Comment: I've rolled your edit back, Kieth was wrong to ask you to edit your solution into your question. That's not a thing we do on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great idea Keith Bennett ! Lambda is a good approach.

I have my solution now:

My module with lambda who run default tests:
**default_tests.rb**

```
module DefaultTest

 Run = ->(*variables_to_test) do
  describe "Default test" do
   variables_to_test.each do |variable|

    it "is Hash" do
      self.class.send(variable).must_be_instance_of Hash
    end

    it "no error return" do
      self.class.send(variable)['error'].must_be_nil
    end

   end
  end
 end

end
```

**test_contacts.rb**

```
module TestAircall
 describe Aircall::Contacts do

  def self.contact_by_id
   @contact_by_id ||= DefaultAircall::AIRCALL.contacts.get_by_id(ENV['TEST_DEFAULT_CONTACT_ID'])
  end

  def self.contact_by_phone_number
   @contact_by_phone_number ||= DefaultAircall::AIRCALL.contacts.get_by_phone_number(ENV['TEST_DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER'])
  end

  def self.contact_by_email
   @contact_by_email ||= DefaultAircall::AIRCALL.contacts.get_by_email(ENV['TEST_DEFAULT_EMAIL'])
  end

  DefaultTest::Run.('contact_by_id', 'contact_by_phone_number', 'contact_by_email')
 end
end
```

**test_users.rb**

```
module TestAircall
 describe Aircall::Users do
  def self.user_by_id
   @user_by_id ||= DefaultAircall::AIRCALL.users.get_by_id(ENV['TEST_DEFAULT_USER_ID'])
  end

  DefaultTest::Run.('user_by_id')
 end
end
```

I can call and run my default tests in every file test for any variable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to do what you are trying to do. The problem here is that the `it` can only be called from within a `describe` block. `it` will not be available in methods *called* by that block.

I did some experimenting. The best I could come up with was that a lambda can be defined within a `describe` block, and used by all `it` blocks in that `describe`. (It is not possible to use a conventional method in this way.)

Here is an example:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

class MyTest < Minitest::Test

  describe 'number test' do

    # It is not legal to define a method here,
    # you'll get this error when trying to call it:
    # "undefined method `is_odd'"

    # def is_odd(number)
    #   it 'is odd' do
    #     assert_equal (number / 2), 1
    #   end
    # end

    is_odd_lambda = ->(number) do
      it 'is odd' do
        assert_equal (number / 2), 1
      end
    end


    # is_odd(3)
    is_odd_lambda.(3)
  end
end
```

Calling the `is_odd` method results in an error, but calling the `is_odd_lambda` does not.

Comment: Good idea ! I have completed with my response.